# ORDER BY percentages with the exception of 100%

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to ORDER BY my percentage discount value. I'd like to show the biggest discounted values first, with the exception of 100% as my 100% discount isn't a discount at all and therefore should be delivers as 0% and in the example statement below, shown at the bottom of the results.

I've looked at the FIELD() function and COALESCE(), but I don't think these offer me an exception, only help with NULL values. I'm currently looking like this:

```
SELECT *, 
   ((rrp-sale_price)/rrp)*100 as percentage
FROM products 
WHERE deleted=0 
GROUP BY linked_id 
ORDER BY percentage DESC, FIELD(percentage, 100) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: `WHERE deleted=0 and percentage < 100`?

Comment: So how you want handle the 100% value in the order? first? last? ignore?

Comment: Ok, ok - I neglected to say that I still want to show the 100% values, however, after 1% at the tail end of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want the 100 first you do:

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN percentage = 100 
               THEN -1
               ELSE percentage 
          END DESC
```

Comment: That's just perfect! Thanks for the education. mySQL amazes me each day.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional sorting:

```
ORDER BY CASE percentage WHEN 100 THEN NULL ELSE percentage END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the percentage constraint to the WHERE clause

```
SELECT *, 
   ((rrp-sale_price)/rrp)*100 as percentage
FROM products 
WHERE deleted=0 AND percentage != 100
GROUP BY linked_id 
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```